# I’ve been hacked and Ubuntu has been loaded to a FTP server. Lost admin privileges.

Tags: remote-access, administrator, restricted-access

I am having a very difficult time. I had Windows 10 on a laptop. Somehow I downloaded a virus. Since then I believe a hacker gained access to my computer through Ip4 and Ip6 or the Pinter Port LP2. My laptop is now completely taken over. I lost all admin privileges. I had the ability for a while to reload Windows 10 through USB then the usb drive stopped  working.  My husband had started using Ubuntu and got rid of Windows.  I realized yesterday that the same thing was happening to his computer. A bumch of files and apps are added that we didn’t add. Now today the settings file is completely missing and the system is on a FTP server that we have no permissions to access. We also have lost ability to download anything. Can someone help us?

Comment: *"Now today the settings file is completely missing"*:  Settings file of what exactly, *"and the system is on a FTP server that we have no permissions to access."*: then how do you know its there? *" We also have lost ability to download anything"* What od you ean by this? When does it fail? Any error message?

Answer (score 1):

At this point, there is no way to 100% insure you're safe without entirely formatting the drives and reinstalling. Anything less is potentially unsafe, so that is the route I suggest you take.

Comment: I absolutely agree with your assessment. However the virus was acquired, it is not going to be completely gone unless the drives are wiped and the OS is reinstalled. As to the ftp server, if login existed before the crash, try logging in once new installation is completed.